# matplotlib doesn't save graph as file on raspberrypi

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, raspberry-pi

I have a question about the matplotlib on raspberry pi
I have following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [100, 200, 500, 700, 300, 200, 500]
x =[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

plt.plot(x, data, color='w')
plt.xlabel('x axis')
plt.ylabel('y axis')
plt.savefig("test.png")
```

The code works perfectly fine on my computer but on the raspberry pi I get following Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.py", line 12, in <module>
    from . import overrides
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/overrides.py", line 7, in <module>
    from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
ImportError: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by /home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-37m-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 107, in <module>
    from . import cbook, rcsetup
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError:

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

Please note and check the following:

  * The Python version is: Python3.7 from "/usr/local/bin/python3"
  * The NumPy version is: "1.19.4"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by /home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-37m-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so)
```

`pip3 freeze` says that my numpy version is 1.19.4

`python3 --version` says that my python version is 3.7.0

How can I fix this Problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fixed it for me
To solve the problem on linux, you need to install the following package:
sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev

https://github.com/Pex2892/PETAL/issues/2